# Conditionally changing the value of a previous row

Tags: sas

I'm looking to conditionally change the value of a variable in the previous row, based on the value of the current row.

For all rows where status=1 then I would like the status in the previous row to also equal 1.

Here is an example data set:

```
ID Status
1    0
1    1
1    1 
2    0
2    1
2    0
2    0
2    1
```

What I would like is:

```
ID Status
1    1
1    1
1    1 
2    1
2    1
2    0
2    1
2    1
```

The code that I want is something like this:

```
if status=1 then lag(status)=status;
```

Note that all my `first.id` have a `status=0`.

That being said, I recognize why this does not work. Please keep in mind that I am very much a beginner programmer and have not understood code given for similar questions asked previously.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a variable for the original row number (`_n_`) you can sort the dataset into reverse order using `descending`, and then use the lag operator:

```
data one;
 infile cards;
 input id status;
 sequence=_n_;
cards;
1 0
1 1
1 1 
2 0
2 1
2 0
2 0
2 1
;
run;

proc sort data=one;
 by id descending sequence;
run;
```

I wasn't sure whether you want the previous values to carry across IDs.  This example doesn't look at the lag values if ID is different (`not first.id`).

```
data two;
 set one;
 by id descending sequence;
 if not first.id and lag(status) = 1 then status=1;
run;

proc sort data=two;
 by id sequence;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you David! I do need to differentiate between IDs such that the process resets for every ID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of it as changing the previous row, you can think of it as a look ahead problem.  That is, when you are reading each record, you want to look ahead at the next record to see if the value of status is 1.

One way to do a look ahead is to merge a dataset with itself.  It's a little tricky, but a good lesson for a beginner who wants to understand the DATA step.  If you merge two datasets without a BY statement, they are smushed together sequentially (first record read from each gets merged together, then second record read from each each, etc.).  If you merge a dataset with itself, and the second time start reading on the second observation, you have a lookahead.  That's a tough sentence, but using your sample data:

```
options mergenoby=nowarn ;

data lookahead ;
  merge have
        have (keep=status rename=(status=NextStatus) firstobs=2)
  ;
run ;

options mergenoby=error ;
```

So the second time you read the dataset, the firstobs option has it start reading on the second observation, and you read only the STATUS variable, and rename it to NextStatus.  The result is:

```
                         Next
 Obs    id    status    Status

  1      1       0         1
  2      1       1         1
  3      1       1         0
  4      2       0         1
  5      2       1         0
  6      2       0         0
  7      2       0         1
  8      2       1         .
```

Take the time to understand the above step, and play with it a bit.  The MERGENOBY option controls whether SAS throws an error, warning, or no warning when a merge step does not have a BY in it.  I always have MERGENOBY set to error, because 99% of the time if a merge step doesn't have a BY statement it's an accidental omission.  When I intentionally do a merge with no by, I set MERGENOBY=NOWARN before the step, and then back to MERGENOBY=ERROR immediately after.  Once you understand how that works all you need is an assignment to get the output you want.

```
options mergenoby=nowarn;

data want;
  merge have
        have (keep=status rename=(status=NextStatus) firstobs=2)
  ;
  if NextStatus=1 then Status=1;
  drop NextStatus;
run;

options mergenoby=error;


Obs    id    status

 1      1       1
 2      1       1
 3      1       1
 4      2       1
 5      2       1
 6      2       0
 7      2       1
 8      2       1
```

Note that is a simple look-ahead, which will look ahead across by values.  So if you ever had the last record of an ID with status=0, and the first record of the next ID with status=1, it would reset the status to 1.  If you didn't want that, you could add logic to check to see if the NextID matches the current ID.

Comment: I don't think that will properly handle multiple ID values. When you are on the last record for ID=1 you do not want to consider the status from the first record for ID=2.

Comment: Agree, that was what I was pointing out in the last paragraph. Wasn't clear to me from the OP's question how they wanted to handle changes in ID, or if they ever had a case where last record for an ID was 0.